# Loading libraries in background in Application Class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, background

I have developed an Android App for which I also have Application Class.

The problem is that I have integrated many services within my app and those service providers require me to initialize the services in the Application Class.

Now the start time of the Application class has drastically increased. Is there any way to initialize the services in a background thread so that they still work and do not slow down the start time of my app.

Any Help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is what I have tried

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InitializeServices();
    }
});

thread.start()
```

Comment: Why don't you init libraries in separate thread ?

Comment: I have tried `new Thread().start` but then it is not initializing the services. Can you please show a small code?

Comment: Show me what you tried ?

Comment: @MD I have edited the question to show what I have tried. Can you please have a look.

Comment: @MD Can you please Help

Comment: @MD Will you please be able to help?

Comment: @MD Thanks for your suggestion. But since I could not figure it out on how to use it I have found another temporary solution which I have posted. :).

Answer (score 1):

After receiving no answer I tried hard to figure out how on how to perform on a separate thread as suggested by @MD but could not figure out. If anyone can figure out would request you to please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Meanwhile, I have moved some initializations from my Application Class to my first Activity and that has helped me a lot to reduce the time.

Answer (score 0):

But this just defers the time. Moving to activity will increase your activity startup time, which again contributes to TTID.
The thing you should do is, add all the sdk initialisation which can be taken to BG thread in a serial executer.